# Computer SMPS is working with high electric shock spreading

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, atx

Sir,

I have a ATX SMPS, today its working and connected LCD monitor will be blinked anonymously, i touch the cabinet I get a electric shock from the cabinet, also CPU working and Its have high electric shock. Now I removed SMPS from the cabinet.. What is this  problem sir.

Comment: Could be a problem with the power supply, or it could be plugged into a mis-wired outlet.  One way or another, something is **very wrong**.

Comment: If this happened suddenly and was OK before it is probably broken and dangerous. BUT if it may have happened before but not been noticed then it MAY be due to Y capacitors in the input filter  + no ground. Your power supply is made to work with an input ground. Has it got one connected? If not, connect one asap. if it has a ground you should not get a shock. If it has a ground and you get a shock then your ground connection is faulty - FIX IT NOW.

Answer (score 5):

It's broke.  Unplug it and throw it away before you get injured or worse.  New power supplies are cheap.

I don't mean to be rude or insulting, so please forgive me.  What I have to say is important and the message is more important than egos or pride.  Power supplies can be dangerous things to work on.  They can kill you.  It's clear from your question that you don't have the knowledge to work on them safely.  I highly advise that you don't work on them.  Instead just throw it away and buy a new one.  Power supplies are cheap, and your life is worth more than that cost.

Answer (score 1):

Before throwing your SMPS away, try to check the earthing of your main plug point, shock in the chassis can also be caused by earthing issues. And I am facing the same because of earthing. Not because of SMPS. Just check the earthing once then change it.